# Postgres Wide To Long by Case/Value

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have a table like:

```
id  grouping   value
1   Group 1      Y
2   Group 1      Y
2   Group 2      Y
3   Group 1      Y
```

I already managed

```
id  Group 1  Group 2
1      Y        
2      Y       
2               Y
3      Y
```

I need to transpose to

```
id  Group 1 Group 2
1     Y       N
2     Y       Y
3     Y       N
```

Comment: Okay sorry did it myself. Created 2 tables with a column per Group each and merged those in a final dataset. Sorry for trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT id
    ,MAX(CASE 
            WHEN grouping = 'Group 1'
                THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
            END) AS "Group 1"
    ,MAX(CASE 
            WHEN grouping = 'Group 2'
                THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
            END) AS "Group 2"
FROM t
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4f8e9/4)